# Setting background image found in sd card

Tags: android

In my application I want to be able to allow users to place in images onto a folder created by my app which then I put them into a stack which will be set up as an image background.

> The question is how would I be able to set a background image on code?

I know you can place images in drawables and set it on xml but I want users to be able to feel free to choose from the background they prefer.

Thanks.

This is what I tried. If possible correct me cause it's not working.

```
Bitmap backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(backgroundFileLocation);
Drawable backgroundImage = new BitmapDrawable(backgroundBitmap);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_layout_options);
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

use a linear layout and setBackgroundDrawable() once you get a drawable from the sd card by loading the image using bitmapfactory.decodefile() then use bitmapDrawable

Comment: I am getting no background change when I try this. I am adding the code on the topic.

Comment: try making sure that the bitmap path is proper.

Comment: also test it with an image in your application resources under the "raw" folder and with one on the sd.

Comment: The path is fine. Image still doesn't load. Must be the code.

Comment: try the bitmapDrawable constructor that takes in the resources object. the one with just a bitmap is deprecated.